# How can I store an array in Ember Data & update each array item in the template?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

I have a Todo-App and now I want to add a list of checkboxes after each task.

When I click a checkbox the correct array item is changed but it's not updated in the template. Furthermore the checkboxes are always filled, even though the value when created is set to false.

I created an array attribute in the DS.Model with DS.Transform for that.

```
Todos.Todo = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    quarters: DS.attr('array')
});
```

Template:

```
{{#each item in quarters}}
    <input type="checkbox" checked=item {{action "checkIndex" _view.contentIndex on="click"}}>
{{/each}}
```

_

```
Todos.TodoController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        checkIndex: function (index) {
            var quarters = this.get('model.quarters');
            var value = quarters[index];

            value = value ? false : true;
            var strIndex = '' + index;
            quarters.set(strIndex, value);

            console.log(this.get('model.quarters')[index]); // --> returns updated value

            this.get('model').save();
        }
        ....
```

It seems like I cannot iterate over the array attribute and render each item seperatly while keeping them updated. I searched a lot for solutions but still didn't figure it out. Or is there a better way to do this?

Iterating over array --> item gets not updated in template:

```
{{#each item in quarters}}
    {{item}}
{{/each}}
```

Array --> get's updated in template:

```
{{quarters}}
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ld7gf/5/

Comment: The problem could be that your model property is "array" of boolean values. Ember does not observe changes on individual data type values of the array. Instead of using "booleans", try a using a hasMany relation to an ember data object which defines a boolean property.

Comment: Thanks @ppcano! I changed the array-attribute 'quarters' to a hasmany relationship. It now fills the checkboxes with the child-attributes. 

When I want to create a new todo-object with child-objects I get the following error message:

" Error: Cannot set read-only property "quarters" on object: <Todos.Todo:ember450:fixture-5> "

Any idea what could be wrong with my approach? 
--> [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Ld7gf/8/)